# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7ffeefc00000)

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am new to C and I am learning algorithms from coursera and here I am trying to implement 3-way quicksort, and I understand that I am encountering a bad memory error and it happens after the array is sorted for the first time.

I am attaching my code here and the page of the java code which the coursera instructor uses, any suggestions to change the error would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void quicksort(int arr[],int low, int high)
{
    if(high<=low)
    return;
    int lt = low;
    int gt = high;
    int pivot = low;
    int  i = low;
    while(i<=gt)
    {
        if(arr[i]==arr[pivot])
            i++;
        else if(arr[i]<arr[pivot])
        {
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[lt]);
            i++;
            lt++;
        }
        else
        {
            swap(&arr[i],&arr[gt]);
            gt++;
        }
    }
    quicksort(arr,low,lt-1);
    quicksort(arr,gt+1,high);
}
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {5,1,2,8,7,5,5,6,5,4,5,3,9,10};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    quicksort(arr, 0, n-1);
    printf("Sorted array: ");
    printArray(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

And I am attaching the picture of the coursera instructor's java code
[Java code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p3Nu.png)

Comment: To learn programming you cannot proceed without learning how to use the debugger. The debugger will tell you exactly the statement where the memory error occurred and you can see which variable is the culprit.

Comment: @johnelemans, I am new to macbook and xcode, I am not giving excuses, however, I take your feedback and will work on it. Thank you so much for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am encountering a bad memory error

you did an error from the Java code

```
    else
    {
        swap(&arr[i],&arr[gt]);
        gt++;
    }
```

must be

```
    else
    {
        swap(&arr[i],&arr[gt]);
        gt--;
    }
```

After that correction, compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra so.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Sorted array: 1 5 2 5 3 4 5 5 5 7 6 8 9 10
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==16601== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16601== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16601== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16601== Command: ./a.out
==16601== 
Sorted array: 1 5 2 5 3 4 5 5 5 7 6 8 9 10 
==16601== 
==16601== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16601==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16601==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==16601== 
==16601== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16601== 
==16601== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16601== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

So now there is no invalid memory access ... but the sort doesn't work, this is because you do not follow the Java code concerning *v* / *pivot*

You have to replace `int pivot = low;` by `int pivot = arr[low];` and of course elsewhere `arr[pivot]` by `pivot`

After that :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra so.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Sorted array: 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

And under *valgrind* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==16833== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16833== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16833== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16833== Command: ./a.out
==16833== 
Sorted array: 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 7 8 9 10 
==16833== 
==16833== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16833==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16833==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==16833== 
==16833== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16833== 
==16833== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16833== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Comment: I tried the int pivot = arr[low], but didn't check on the greater than part, thanks for guiding me.